# Woocommerce Order: a cart for every category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

This is the question. Every order on the website must be done for each category. Example: I have two categories Books and Pencils. I can order books or pencils, finish the order with the cart and then I can ordinare another other category. Is it possible? Is there a plugin? Or what is the code?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It does not make sense what are you looking for?

Comment: I solved. I past the code for other person they have the same problem in more comments. add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_one_product_category_allowed', 20, 3 );
function only_one_product_category_allowed( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {

    // Getting the product categories term slugs in an array for the current product
    $term_slugs   = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'slugs') );

Comment: // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){

        // Check if the product category of the current product don't match with a cart item
        if( ! has_term( $term_slugs, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ){

Comment: // Displaying a custom notice
            wc_add_notice( __('Il prodotto non può essere aggiunto: è possibile acquistare solo per un brand alla volta. '), 'error' );
wc_add_notice(
            sprintf( __( ' <a href="http://www.sifood.it/testecommerce/shop/">Ritorna allo shop e compra prodotti della categoria che stai già ordinando</a>', 'your_theme_domain'),
                $button_url,
                $button_title
            ), 'error'
        );

            // Avoid add to cart
            return false; // exit
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}